# Using a Point Process model for Prediction

Tags: r, geospatial, spatstat

I am analysing ambulance incident data. The dataset covers three years and has roughly 250000 incidents.
Preliminary analysis indicates that the incident distribution is related to population distribution.
Fitting a point process model using spatstat agrees with this, with broad agreement in a partial residual plot.
However, it is believed that the trend diverges from this population related trend during the "social hours", that is Friday, Saturday night, public holidays.

I want to take subsets of the data and see how they differ from the gross picture. How do I account for the difference in intensity due to the smaller number of points inherent in a subset of the data?

Or is there a way to directly use my fitted model for the gross picture?

It is difficult to provide data as there are privacy issues, and with the size of the dataset, it's hard to simulate the situation. I am not by any means a statistician, hence I am flundering a bit here. I have a copy of
"Spatial Point Patterns Methodology and Applications with R"  which is very useful.

I will try with pseudocode to explain my methodology so far..

```
250k_pts.ppp <- ppp(the_ambulance_data x and y, the_window)
1.3m_census_pts <- ppp(census_data x and y, the_window)
```

Best bandwidth for the density surface by visual inspection seemed to be `bw.scott`. This was used to fit a density surface for the points.

```
inc_density <- density(250k_pts.ppp, bw.scott)
pop_density <- density(1.3m_census_pts, bw.scott)

fit0 <- ppm(inc_density ~ 1)
fit_pop <- ppm(inc_density ~ pop_density)

partials <- parres(fit_pop, "pop_density")
```

Plotting the partial residuals shows that the agreement with the linear fit is broadly acceptable, with some areas of 'wobble'..

What I am thinking of doing next:

```
the_ambulance_data %>% group_by(day_of_week, hour_of_day) %>% 
select(x_coord, y_coord) %>% nest() -> nested_day_hour_pts
```

Taking one of these list items and creating a ppp, say fri_2300hr_ppp;

```
fri23.den <- density(fri_2300hr_ppp, bw.scott)
fit_fri23 <- fit(fri_2300hr_ppp ~ pop_density)
```

How do I then compare this ppp or density with the broader model?  I can do characteristic tests such as dispersion, clustering..  Can I compare the partial residuals of `fit_pop` and `fit_fri23`?

How do I control for the effect of the number of points on the density - i.e. I have 250k points versus maybe 8000 points in the subset. I'm thinking maybe quantiles of the density surface?

Comment: This doesn't seem like a specific programming question that's appropriate for Stack Overflow. If you have general questions about statistical methods, you should probably ask over at [stats.se] or [datascience.se] or if it's specific to geographical data, maybe [gis.se].

Comment: I would argue that the OP might only need to add some example data and some lines of code showing what he did so far, so we can understand the problem and see it as a programming problem in R/spatstat. On the other hand you may be right and Cross Validated would be a better fit. Anyway, a more specific example with (fake/subset) data and fitted models would help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Attach marks to the ambulance data representing the subset/categories of interest (eg 'busy' vs 'non-busy'). For an informal or nonparametric analysis, use tools like `relrisk`, or use `density.splitppp` after separating the different types of points using `split.ppp`. For a formal analysis (taking into account the sample sizes etc etc) you should fit several candidate models to the same data, one model having a busy/nonbusy effect and another model having no such effect, then use `anova.ppm` to test formally whether there is a busy/nonbusy effect. See Chapter 14 of the book mentioned.